# copied files from windows to ext4 hdd now cannot see in linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, filesystems

I am working on setting up a server running in linux and I formatted my external HDD as ext4.  I used paragon software to transfer files from my windows desktop onto the ext4 HDD.  Now, when I plug that HDD into the linux system, I cannot see any of the files.  But the space has been taken up.  Does anyone know how I can get access to them?

Also, I can no longer see the files on Windows when I plug the drive in.

Comment: did you safely eject the device on Windows before moving it to Linux?

Comment: As far as I know, ext4 on Windows is mostly for reading, since it's very bad on writing. For transferring between Linux & Windows, FAT32 may be the best option, or even NTFS.

Comment: @Mokubai yes it was safely ejected

Comment: The only safe way to write to ext4 on Windows based on my negative experiences is via WSL2: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

Comment: Ahh,, didnt know about that.  So are my files lost basically?

Comment: You might try DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/, which can mount an ext*n* partition, to try to recover files from the external HDD -- however, I would not rust the file system on the HDD now, and suggest reformatting, whether or not you can recover files. Unlike Windows, Linux is able to handle a large variety of file systems, though you might need to install *fuse* on some Linux versions to use NTFS.